# Timer object doubles when I change activity and come back

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

So I'm trying to make a clicker game that is about money. Every time you click the middle button it gives you 1€, but it also gives 1€/second.
I'm having a problem when I go to the shop activity and then come back to MainActivity, it counts as 2 timers are running, and if I alternate activities again, it counts as if 3 Timers were running at the same time. Thats giving me issues because I declared "money_per_sec" int, and dont want 2€/s or more just because I click on "Shop".
Any help?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            money = loadGame.getInt("money", 0);
            money_per_sec = loadGame.getInt("money_per_sec", 0);
            money_per_click = loadGame.getInt("money_per_click", 0);

            money = money + money_per_sec;

            SharedPreferences saveGame = getSharedPreferences(SAVE, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
            editor.putInt("money", money);
            editor.putInt("money_per_sec", money_per_sec);
            editor.apply();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    tv_money_per_sec.setText(String.valueOf(money_per_sec));
                    tv_money_per_click.setText(String.valueOf(money_per_click));
                    toolbar_title.setText(String.valueOf(money));
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check which **Activity**'s *life-cycle* method are you using for starting your *timer*. I think you are using *onResume* which case this problem, and you start another timer by getting back to your **Activity**.

you can take a look at this diagram and choose the best position, or even separate your timer from activity life-cycle:

[image: Activity Life-Cycle Diagram]

also you can implement Application class and place your timer there. this class is instantiated once during your application life time:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private OnTimerTick listener;

    public void setListener(OnTimerTick listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // start your timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                money = loadGame.getInt("money", 0);
                money_per_sec = loadGame.getInt("money_per_sec", 0);
                money_per_click = loadGame.getInt("money_per_click", 0);

                money = money + money_per_sec;

                SharedPreferences saveGame = getSharedPreferences(SAVE, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
                editor.putInt("money", money);
                editor.putInt("money_per_sec", money_per_sec);
                editor.apply();

                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onTick(money,money_per_sec);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }

    interface OnTimerTick {
        void onTick(int money, int moneyPerSec);
    }
}
```

you have to add this to your manifest like this:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...
```

also you can access this singleton class every where in your application:

```
MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

inside your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyApplication.OnTimerTick {
    private MyApplication application;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        application = (MyApplication) getApplication();

        // other stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        application.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        application.setListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(final int money, final int moneyPerSec) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv_money_per_sec.setText(String.valueOf(moneyPerSec));
                    tv_money_per_click.setText(String.valueOf(moneyPerSec));
                    toolbar_title.setText(String.valueOf(money));
                }
            });
    }
```

This is how you can even access the Timer within any other activity you like.

Comment: I'm actually using onCreate in all other activities, but the fun part is, that when I change activity, the timer still runs. And when I go back to the activity that has the Timer, it "creates" another timer. Altho, if I restart the app everythin is normal until I switch activities again. I don't know if I'm explaining myself too well, I'm sorry. But thanks for help.

Comment: I'm using Intents to start another Activity

Comment: Okay, then the best way is to separate the timer and place it in Application class which create and remains alive during your app life time.

Comment: But by default it says my MainActivity is extending AppCompatActivity, how do I find the Application class. I'm sorry if its too obvious, but I'm still noob at this xD

Comment: I have add more detail about how to use Application class in your application to my answer.

Comment: So I can make the class and put my timer there with all the SharedPreferences variables and it will work just fine? Imma try it in a bit, I'm not home yet, I'll tell you the results. Thank you!

Comment: Good luck, I am here for further questions.

Comment: Ok so I got home just now, I made the class MyApplication, I made it extend Application, I can declare a Timer, but I can't use timer.scheduleAtFixedRate for some reason, got any idea why?

Comment: What is the error you get?! I don't think there be any limitation!

Comment: I wrote Timer timer = new Timer();

Comment: But the then when I got to write timer.scheduleAtFixedRate the object timer I created didnt even appear

Comment: Okay, I will add more detail to my answer with whole implementation :)

Comment: It's giving me an error on listener.OnTimerTick, it cant resolve symbol listener, where did you declare it?

Comment: It is placed inside MyApplication class, you can also declare it in a separate java file.

Comment: Right, but on private OnTimerTick listener; the OnTimerTick is red, there is some options like create OnTimerTick.class

Comment: My mistake, change it to **onTick**

Comment: It's working well, but when I change activities, it shows the last number on the title for a split second, other than that works like a charm!

Comment: Is there a way to remove it or do will I just have to live with it? xD

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point! You can set your Actionbar title in any activity.

Comment: Its like on MainActivity it says 300€ for example, when I change to the shopActivity and then come back to the MainActivity, it shows 300€ for a split second on the ActionBar, when it should have update instantly, I would think

Comment: Aha, onResume you can clean the text and wait for the next tick or set a variable in application and load it onResume.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so bad but I'm new to this, could you be a little bit more specific please? xD

Comment: protected void onResume() { toolbar_title.setText(""); }

Comment: finally, if this answer works for you, give it a green tick ;)

Comment: before or after super.OnResume

Comment: Ok I did that but the split second non update title is still there :/

Comment: I hope you have fixed the issue till now, but if not, I suggest to take another look at Activity life-cycle and choose a method to clean the unwanted number when you get back to you activity. if not open up another question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably consider using [a `Handler` instead of a `Timer`](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html). This will allow you to more easily manage your `Timer` within the lifecycle of the `Activity`.

```
private final int interval = 1000; // 1 Second
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "C'Mom no hands!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
...
handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

Next, based on your comment:

> I'm actually using onCreate in all other activities, but the fun part
>   is, that when I change activity, the timer still runs. And when I go
>   back to the activity that has the Timer, it "creates" another timer.

It looks like you are using the standard [`launchMode`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for your `Activity`. This `launchMode` will create a new `Activity` when the `Back` or `Up` buttons are pressed because the second `Activity` is creating an `Intent` to start that `Activity`.

Try setting the `launchMode` for the `Activity` with the `Timer` to `android:launchMode="singleTop"`. This will instead route the `Intent` from the second `Activity` to the existing parent `Activity`, and trigger a call to `onNewIntent`. This will prevent the `Activity` from being restarted, and creating another `Timer`.

You should also probably terminate the `Timer` in the `onDestroy` method of your `Activity`, otherwise it will continue to run and could cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your timer an instance of the activity rather than an anonymous class. Check if it is already running in `onResume()`. If not, start it. Stop it in `onDestroy()`. Something like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Timer mTimer;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mTimer == null) {
            mTimer = new Timer() {
            };
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not see the point of running the timer in the background if all it does is update the UI. This does not make sense if the activity is not even visible.